# Hardware Virtualization on Dell Latitude E6500

Tags: windows-8, virtualization, dell-latitude, intel-core2, windows-phone-8

I have a Dell Latitude E6500 with an Intel Core2Duo processor and 4 GB RAM. I am running Windows 8 Pro 64-bit. In the BIOS (revision A25) settings, I have enabled Intel Virtualization Technology, but not VT for Direct I/O or Trusted Execution.

I have installed Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate and the Windows Phone 8.0 SDK, however, at the end of the installation, I get a dialog that says "This computer does not support hardware virtualization, which means Windows Phone Emulator 8.0 can't run on this PC."

I've tried various combinations of the Intel virtualization settings (VT, VT for Direct I/O, Trusted Execution) to no avail.

Why am I getting this message? Is the Intel Virtualization Technology not really hardware virtualization? Do I need more RAM (I can have up to 8 GB)?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148828/unable-to-create-the-virtual-machine

Comment: Your CPU lacks SLAT. The Windows Server version of Hyper-V can run the emulator without SLAT, but of course, that's not a workstation.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I need to look into a new laptop. This one will only take a Core 2 processor.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to get a new laptop with any Intel Core i3, i5 or i7 based machine as all of those do support SLAT. However, you may want consider a workaround that I am using.

I have a need to run VMWare on the primary desktop thus I can't enable Hyper-V at the same time. The way around it was to:

```
Install VMWare Workstation v9 on your host OS
Install Windows 8 64-bit as a guest OS
Enable virtualization in Hardware → Processors and select these settings:
    preferred mode: Intel VT-x/EPT
    virtualized Intel Vt-X - selected
```

The rest is unchecked.

[image]

This will allow you to run the Windows 8 SDK/emulator in the VMWare instance